# Lex and Yacc segmentation fault

Tags: c, linux, yacc, lex

I'm trying to write a parser for mini-c using lex and yacc. Incase of single line inputs it work pretty well in case of multi line inputs it is throwing a segmentation fault. Running GDB did not help.

c.l file

```
alpha [a-zA-Z]
digit [0-9]
%{
#include <stdlib.h>
void yyerror(char *);
#include "y.tab.h"
%}


%%
[ \t]       ;
[ \n]   { yylineno = yylineno + 1;}
int return INT;
float return FLOAT;
char return CHAR;
void return VOID;
double return DOUBLE;
for     return FOR;
while   return WHILE;
if  return IF;
else    return ELSE;
printf  return PRINTF;
struct  return STRUCT;
^"#include ".+ ;
{digit}+       return NUM;
{alpha}({alpha}|{digit})* return ID;
"<="    return LE;
">="    return GE;
"=="    return EQ;
"!="    return NE;
">" return GT;
"<" return LT;
"."     return DOT;
\/\/.* ;
\/\*(.*\n)*.*\*\/ ;
.       return yytext[0];
%%
```

c.y file

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int yylex(void);
extern FILE *fp;
extern FILE *yyin;
extern int yylineno;
extern char* yytext;
%}
%token INT FLOAT CHAR DOUBLE VOID
%token FOR WHILE 
%token IF ELSE PRINTF 
%token STRUCT 
%token NUM ID
%token INCLUDE
%token DOT
%right '='
%left AND OR
%left '<' '>' LE GE EQ NE LT GT
%%
start:  Function 
    | Declaration
    ;
/* Declaration block */
Declaration: Type Assignment ';' 
    | Assignment ';'    
    | FunctionCall ';'  
    | ArrayUsage ';'    
    | Type ArrayUsage ';'   
    | StructStmt ';'    
    | error 
    ;
/* Assignment block */
Assignment: ID '=' Assignment
    | ID '=' FunctionCall
    | ID '=' ArrayUsage
    | ArrayUsage '=' Assignment
    | ID ',' Assignment
    | NUM ',' Assignment
    | ID '+' Assignment
    | ID '-' Assignment
    | ID '*' Assignment
    | ID '/' Assignment 
    | NUM '+' Assignment
    | NUM '-' Assignment
    | NUM '*' Assignment
    | NUM '/' Assignment
    | '\'' Assignment '\''  
    | '(' Assignment ')'
    | '-' '(' Assignment ')'
    | '-' NUM
    | '-' ID
    |   NUM
    |   ID
    ;

/* Function Call Block */
FunctionCall : ID'('')'
    | ID'('Assignment')'
    ;

/* Array Usage */
ArrayUsage : ID'['Assignment']'
    ;

/* Function block */
Function: Type ID '(' ArgListOpt ')' CompoundStmt 
    ;
ArgListOpt: ArgList
    |
    ;
ArgList:  ArgList ',' Arg
    | Arg
    ;
Arg:    Type ID
    ;
CompoundStmt:   '{' StmtList '}'
    ;
StmtList:   StmtList Stmt
    |
    ;
Stmt:   WhileStmt
    | Declaration
    | ForStmt
    | IfStmt
    | PrintFunc
    | ';'
    ;

/* Type Identifier block */
Type:   INT 
    | FLOAT
    | CHAR
    | DOUBLE
    | VOID 
    ;

/* Loop Blocks */ 
WhileStmt: WHILE '(' Expr ')' Stmt  
    | WHILE '(' Expr ')' CompoundStmt 
    ;

/* For Block */
ForStmt: FOR '(' Expr ';' Expr ';' Expr ')' Stmt 
       | FOR '(' Expr ';' Expr ';' Expr ')' CompoundStmt 
       | FOR '(' Expr ')' Stmt 
       | FOR '(' Expr ')' CompoundStmt 
    ;

/* IfStmt Block */
IfStmt : IF '(' Expr ')' 
        Stmt 
    ;

/* Struct Statement */
StructStmt : STRUCT ID '{' Type Assignment '}'  
    ;

/* Print Function */
PrintFunc : PRINTF '(' Expr ')' ';'
    ;

/*Expression Block*/
Expr:   
    | Expr LE Expr 
    | Expr GE Expr
    | Expr NE Expr
    | Expr EQ Expr
    | Expr GT Expr
    | Expr LT Expr
    | Assignment
    | ArrayUsage
    ;
%%
#include<ctype.h>
int count=0;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");

   if(!yyparse())
        printf("\nParsing complete\n");
    else
        printf("\nParsing failed\n");

    fclose(yyin);
    return 0;
}

yyerror(char *s) {
    printf("%d : %s %s\n", yylineno, s, yytext );
}
```

Comment: Are you using the latest versions of lex and yacc?

Comment: Yes. Installed it again from terminal today.

Comment: it might help if you gave an example input that fails

Comment: Input: int a; passes but int a;int b; throws segmentation fault

Answer (score 0):

```
extern char* yytext;
```

If you're using *lex(1)* and not *flex(1)*, `yytext` is a `char[]`, not a `char *`.

However you should certainly be using *flex(1)* if possible and available. It's been superior from practically the moment of its release around 1987. *lex(1)* is just a historical curiousity now.

Comment: Yes you are correct..may I know what difference it makes and why it works correctly for single line input. Can you please clarify?

Comment: You want to know the difference between `char[]` and `char*`?